# Conditional statements on variables added to constraints in linear programming

Tags: python, python-3.x, pulp

I am looking for the best way to model and solve the following linear problem using Pulp where I have conditional statements on my variables to be added to the constraints:

Here is an example:

```
Max (x1*100 - a*80 - b*100) + (x2*80 - c*120 - d*75)
```

s.t.

`a + b = x1`

`c + d = x2`

`x1 > 0`

`x2 > 0`

`if x1 > 0 then x2 = 0`

`if x2 > 0  then x1 = 0`

`a, b, c, d <= 100`

I have declared x1, x2, a, b, c, and d as variables in my pulp problem.

I tried to add 2 indicator functions in my obj function (one for x1 and one for x2) but they are not accepted by Pulp.

I found some good answers:
[Converting conditional constraints to linear constraints in Linear Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134522/converting-conditional-constraints-to-linear-constraints-in-linear-programming)

But do not know the exact wording to use to code it.

Comment: What are your two indicator functions?

Comment: initially I looked at doing:

'Max (x1*100 - a*80 - b*100) * 1(x2=0,1,0) + (x2*80 - c*120 - d*75)*1(x1=0,1,0)'

1 being the indicator function equals to 1 if the condition is true or 0 if it's false

Comment: I also tried to make these indicator functions as binary variables (0 or 1) for pulp
'Max (x1*100 - a*80 - b*100) *indi1 + (x2*80 - c*120 - d*75)*indic2' with an additional constraint indic1 + indic2 = 1 and let Pulp optimize them as well, but it did not like that I multiply 2 variables together (x1 with indic1 and x2 with indic2)

Comment: from your constrains, your objective function should be equivalent to MAX (a * 20 - c * 40 + d * 5). Also you can´t make > constrains, only >=. It is also unclear if a,b,c,d are integers or continuous

Comment: I agree with your comments, thanks for the pointing it out.
a, b, c, d, are integers as well.
The solution I am looking for is really to model a way so that if the left part of the pblm (x1, a ,b) take any value then the other side can't (must be 0) and vice versa. it's like you have 2 states of nature, you can't be in both and you have to pick the side that maximize the value. let me know if it's not clear

Comment: Welcome to SO! Given your last comment I think it would be helpful if you explain what you are trying to achieve with your condition. If it is really that you can either have non-zero values for the first term (x1, a, b) OR non-sero values for the second term (x2, c, d) then I think there are easier ways to achieve what you want. Are ALL of your variables non-negative integers?

Comment: Thanks kadbulla ! You have a very fair point, so here comes the novel: 
So let's say we have two states of nature but you cannot be in both at the same time, you have to pick one side.
Each state generates a revenue that you try to maximize based on the constraints you may have for each (the constants input and the max size).
Left part is the revenue from state 1: (x1*100 - a*80 - b*100)
Right part is the revenue from state 2: (x2*80 - c*120 - d*75)

Comment: In my initial post I used a function to maximize the overall state (sum of all states) but I need a kind of switch on/off way to force Pulp to not consider the other part (both x1 and x2 are positive).
So I tried initially to: 'Max (x1*100 - a*80 - b*100) * 1(x2=0,1,0) + (x2*80 - c*120 - d*75)*1(x1=0,1,0)' but Pulp did not like to have an objective function with a if and returned an error

Comment: Then I tried to make and add these indicator functions as binary variables (0 or 1) and 'Max (x1*100 - a*80 - b*100) *indi1 + (x2*80 - c*120 - d*75)*indic2' with an additional constraint: 'indic1 + indic2 = 1' (to make sure you cannot be in both states) and let Pulp optimize these variable as well.
But it did not like that I was multipling 2 variables together (x1 with indic1 and x2 with indic2)

Comment: Another solution would be to not create x1 and x2 variables and just create only one variable x that can be either positive or negative and rewrite the pblm as follow:
'Max indic1(x) * rev1(x) + indic2(x) * rev2(x)' which more or less the same and will still face the issue to handle indicator functions.
In the way i posted it, yes ALL variables are non-negative integers.
In this example the solution might sound trivial but I wanted to extend it later to a bigger problem where X is a vector of 10000 elements and the solution becomes less obvious (meaning an algo has to solve it)

Comment: Maybe also [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43783848/pulp-lp-minimization-formulating-select-one-type-constraint/58305832#58305832) with a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Make 2 Binary Variables X1 and X2

Then set

```
X1+X2 <=1
```

And

```
0 <= x1 <= X1*M
0 <= x2 <= X2*M
```

where M is a sufficiently large number (note the smaller M is the easier the problem is to solve)