# Can you model indicator constraints with pulp?

Tags: python, constraints, pulp

I want to add indicator constraints (e.g. `if z=0, then x=0` with `x>=0` and `z` being a binary variable) to my problem written in `PuLP`. Obviously, I could make use of the big-M method as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43783848/pulp-lp-minimization-formulating-select-one-type-constraint) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171854/conditional-statements-on-variables-added-to-constraints-in-linear-programming).

However, I cannot use the big-M workaround since my term is unbounded within the MILP. I found [this post from 2016](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pulp-or-discuss/uT6zZEdITOU/FaqwoPPgGwAJ) stating that `PuLP` cannot handle indicator constraints.

Does anyone know if that is still the case or any other solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the term is unbounded, just put a really big value for M (hence the name). The solution time is better if M is as tight as it can be but alot of people use a value like 9999999

Comment: From your answer I assume that it is still not possible to do so. I'm combining ML with LP, hence prediction of the target value and its optimization happen simultaneously. It's therefore hard to derive bounds for big-M. Setting a high value for M may yield numerical issues, but I will do so, if there is no alternative. Thank you anyway!

Comment: If you would like to use indicator constraints I suggest you use the gurobi python interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can try to handle Binary indicator_constraint with GEKKO `if2` or `if3` methods (if that what you meant)

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np


tm= np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
cost= np.array([4, 31, 30, 28, 28, 27, 26, 26, 25, 24, 24, 23 ])
d = np.array([ 0, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18])
cnt= len(tm); print(len(tm))
new_cost = 18
    
m = GEKKO(remote = False)

# Gekko has an integer tolerance where it can find a solution within 1e-2 of the integer value. This can be adjusted with the solver option minlp_integer_tol
# increase tolerance
m.options.RTOL = 1e-10
m.options.OTOL = 1e-10

m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-5',\
                    'minlp_maximum_iterations 10000',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 10000',\
                    'minlp_integer_tol 1e-8']

x = m.Array(m.Var,cnt,lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)

# !!!
x1= m.Const(1)
x0= m.Const(0)
m.Maximize(m.sum([ (cost[i]- d[i] -  m.if3(cost[i]- d[i] , x1, x0) *new_cost)  *x[i]  for i in range(cnt) ]))
y = m.Var()
m.Equation(y==m.sum([  (cost[i]- d[i] -  m.if3(cost[i]- d[i] , x1, x0) *new_cost)  *x[i]  for i in range(cnt)] ))

m.options.SOLVER = 1        #  APOPT
m.solve()

value = -1* m.options.objfcnval     # Maximize need *-1 to get max_val
print("y_total_: ", y.value[0])
# print('Option: ' + str(x))
```

p.s. or see in GEKKO Special Ordered Set [SOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61398946/15893581) in GEKKO,  also described e.g. in [lp_solve](https://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.1/) - milp solver